# putting the most visited content in a block

Tags: views, 7, rating

I need to have the most visited content on a block, I am using view module and I want to know is there any way to do it with view module or I should use an other module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Drupal Most Popular](https://www.drupal.org/project/mostpopular) module

> Showcase the most popular content across your Drupal website and
>   engage your audience. Ready to Use
>
> The module is pre-packaged with several services including:
>
> Drupal - Most Viewed pages (using Statistics module) Drupal - Most
>   Commented pages (from simple database query) Google Analytics - Most
>   Viewed pages AddThis.com - Most Shared pages Disqus.com - Most
>   Commented pages The system defines Drupal hooks to allow new services
>   to be created, which can pull data from third party providers or
>   internally from Drupal.  The system also provides an API to help
>   service plugins normalize their results and exclude certain pages, as
>   configured by the administrator.

or another module that you can use and its so easy is [Radioactivity](https://www.drupal.org/project/radioactivity) and there is a good video tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vxXeJASe-QM)

Comment: Thank you Mohammad. I should say you have a grate name I love Mohammad

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer rolling your own code, the [statistics module](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21statistics%21statistics.module/7) is a great start.